# Install MTPro2 on macOS Sierra 10.12

Tags: mactex, mtpro, macos

I am trying to install `MTPro2` following the instructions [here](http://math.nyu.edu/~fennell/mtpro2/). I have MacTex 2017 installed.

```
$ ./mtpro2-texlive.sh -i ../mtp2lite.zip.tpm
Installing MathTime Professional 2 from ../mtp2lite.zip.tpm.
Unpacking ../mtp2lite.zip.tpm.
Copying files.
Installing MathTime Professional 2.
  > running texhash
  > updating map references
  > editing updmap.cfg
  > updating TeX Live databases
TeX Live updated; checking that MTPro2 works...
Succesfully compiled LaTeX file with MTPro2 included.
MathTime Professional 2 installed.
Documentation available at /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/docs/
```

Once the compilation is done, I use `latexmk -pdf document.tex` to generate pdf. The sample document that I use is taken from [here](https://github.com/dustinvtran/latex-templates/blob/master/papers/main.tex).

When I run the command, I get the following error:

```
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -recorder  "some.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) 
(preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
[................................................]
kpathsea: Running mktextfm mt2syat
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; 
nonstopmode; input mt2syat
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded base=mf)

kpathsea: Running mktexmf mt2syat
! I can't find file `mt2syat'.
<*> ...=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input mt2syat

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input mt2syat
```

It looks like a path problem, however, I could not figure out what is actually the issue. I would appreciate any pointer.

Thanks

Comment: Follow the instructions on their website, http://www.pctex.com/kb/57.html .

Comment: I don't see where sudo is being used in you console output. Also, that Cpndole output says it was able you compile the test document. Finally, what does the log output by that script have to say about where things were were installed?

Comment: @JPi - thanks for the reference. I did not manage to locate the [mtp2fonts/texmf, lucimatx/texmf]. It does not seem to be included in the installation. Having said that, the target directory appears to be populated by PCTeX files (e.g., /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/tfm/pctex/mtpro2/*.tfm) texhash output: texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-config/ls-R...
texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/ls-R...
texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/ls-R...
texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/ls-R...
texhash: Done.

Comment: and here is the output of the remapping --  sudo -H updmap-sys --enable Map=mtpro2.map
updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap may write changes to the following updmap.cfg file:
  /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg unchanged.  Map files not recreated.
updmap: Updating ls-R files.

Comment: @HerbSchulz - thank you for your comment. The script completes the pdf conversion and I get the output document in pdf - albeit with errors. This is the error: ! Font U/mt2sya/m/n/14.4=mt2syat at 14.4pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not 
found.

Comment: Do you indeed have a mtpro2.map file and where is it located? I'd expect it to be in /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-local/fonts/map or a sub-directory of that directory? Also, are there type1, .pfb, files installed (you mention the .tfm files). Also, do you have a sub-set of the mtpro2 fonts or the full set; I seem to have a mt2syat font.

Comment: Since it can't find the .tfm file for mt2syat please check /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-local/fonts/tfm (and sub-directories to see if you, in fact, do have a mt2syat.tfm file.

Comment: Dear Herb, thank you very much for taking your time to help me. mtpro2.map file is located at /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-local/fonts/map/dvips/mtpro2. I checked to see if I have mt2stay.tfm and it does not exist - .tfm files that are found in the folder: mt2exa.tfm  mt2exg.tfm  mt2mbt.tfm  mt2mit.tfm  mt2syt.tfm
mt2exe.tfm  mt2mbf.tfm  mt2mif.tfm  mt2syf.tfm  mt2xl.tfm
mt2exf.tfm  mt2mbs.tfm  mt2mis.tfm  mt2sys.tfm  mt2xxxl.tfm

Comment: That would explain why it can't be found. Did you purchase the full mtpro2 or the lite version? What is your preamble?

Comment: Oh, I see. Somehow I assumed that this popular font is already included in the lite version (which I have). This is the preamble that I use: https://github.com/dustinvtran/latex-templates/tree/master/papers/preamble